# How can I run @Async properly in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous

Read countless of articles and Stackoverflow questions (too many, just not gonna list them), still my `@Async` doesn't seem to work as expected.

**What I'm trying to do?**

1. Public method A() print A 100 times, sitting at class `AsyncServiceImpl`
2. Public method B() print A 100 times, sitting at class `AsyncServiceImpl`
3. Both method A & B is called by another method C(), sitting at class `anotherClassImpl`

**Current result**

```
A A A A (after 100 times printing of A...) B B B B (Follow by 100 times printing of B)
```

**Result expected to be:**

```
A A A A B B A A A A B B B A A ... B A .... 

## Since both methods run asynchronously, I expect mixed of printing.
```

### Actual Codes

class anotherServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class anotherServiceImpl implements anotherService{
    @Override
    public void C() {
        AsyncServiceImpl.A();
        AsyncServiceImpl.B();
    }
}
```

class AsyncServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class AsyncServiceImpl {
    @Async("processExecutor")
    public static void A() {
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

    @Async("processExecutor")
    public static void B() {
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }
}
```

**Few check marks**

1. @EnableAsync is added at my main starting Class which look something like

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncTestAPI {

    public static void main(String[] args) { SpringApplication.run(AsyncTestAPI.class, args); }

    @Bean(name="processExecutor")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(100);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(200);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("GithubLookup-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

}
```

2. Methods that annotated with @Async is public
3. Methods that annotated with @Async is not sitting in the same class from where is being called
4. Setup `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`

#### My True goal

My ultimate goal is to use `@Async` to

- do some processing on given business logic
- Hibernate.saveAll() / .save() / .etc (some actions with Database)

Comment: `async` is designed to use the clock cycles that are being wasted while your methods are waiting on a result.  It doesn't require multiple threads; why do you think you need them?

Comment: Hi @RobertHarvey,  I have just updated my true goals at the bottom of my ques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because you have declared those methods as static.  Since `AsyncServiceImpl` is a Spring stereotyped Service, drop the static from the method definitions, and in the class that you're calling these methods, call them through the injected proxy.  Here's an example:

```
@Service
public class AsyncServiceImpl {
    @Async("processExecutor")
    public void A() {
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

    @Async("processExecutor")
    public void B() {
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }
}

@Service
public class AnotherServiceImpl implements AnotherService {
    private final AsyncServiceImpl asyncService;
    
    public AnotherServiceImpl(AsyncServiceImpl asyncService) {
        this.asyncService = asyncService;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void C() {
        asyncService.A();
        asyncService.B();
    }
}
```

Here are some other tips.  Your class AsyncServiceImpl doesn't implement an interface; name it AsyncService.  `anotherServiceImpl` and `anotherService` should be named, AnotherServiceImpl and AnotherService.  Those are good habits to get into even when you're just typing a question in SO.

Comment: Hats off to you first of all. Solution works like a charm, I previously added `static` with the help of suggestion in IDE. Total stuck. 2ndly, I did try `implements AsyncService` for `AsyncServiceImpl`, however it's throwing me `The bean 'asyncServiceImpl' could not be injected because it is a JDK dynamic proxy`. Again, it works as expected when I remove `implements AsyncService`.

Comment: Fixed the error `JDK dynamic proxy`.. auto wired to `asyncService` resolved :)